# Image calling from external server hangs IE6

Tags: html, image, jsp, internet-explorer-6, jstl

I Have Table with multiple columns and rows,

Example,

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
   <th>Head 1</th>
   <th>Head 2</th>
   <th>Head 3</th>
</tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
<tr>
   <td>Data 1</td>
   <td>
      //Image is loaded from external URL.
      <img src="${Url}/school/${value}/image?size=tb" />
    </td> 
   <td>Data 3</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

**Problem:** This is working fine in all the browser but in IE6 browser hangs. My Table just having 10 records. (If I remove the image then working fine.)

Please some one give me some ideas on this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a `cross-browser` issue. Have you tried to **not close** the `img` tag? I mean try this,

```
  <img src="${Url}/school/${value}/image?size=tb">
```

**BTW, it should not matter, actually.**

Comment: @Max: get to the source of the `HTML` page, copy the `URL` of the image, and fire that thing in the address bar. Lets see if you can get the image.

Comment: Ya, I am getting the image. This is working in all other browsers except IE6

Comment: Hey, I just figured it out and the answer is pathetic. In my company proxy server is stopping the external link from loading. Thanks ansari, this just got figured when u say to use image url in address bar.